# I can't use if statement in OnChange

Tags: swift, swiftui

first of all I have two textfields and when one of them is focused and changed something this textfield that is changed has to convert a number to the other textfield so my code of the textfield look like this

```
@State var leftAmount = ""
@State var rightAmount = ""

@State var showInfoScreen = false
@State var showSelectCurrency = false

@FocusState var leftTyping
@FocusState var rightTyping

@State var leftCurrency: Currency = .silverPiece
@State var rightCurrency: Currency = .goldPiece

var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        Image("background")
            .resizable()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        
        VStack{
            Image("prancingpony")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(height: 200)
            
            Text("Curreny Exchange")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .kerning(2)
            
            HStack{
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        Image(leftCurrency.image)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(height: 33)
                        
                        Text(leftCurrency.name)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        showSelectCurrency = true
                    }.sheet(isPresented: $showSelectCurrency){
                        SelectCurrency(showSelectCurrency: $showSelectCurrency, topCurrency: $leftCurrency, bottomCurrency: $rightCurrency)
                    }
                    
                    TextField("Amount", text: $leftAmount)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .focused($leftTyping)
                        .onChange(of: leftAmount) { newValue in
                            if leftTyping {
                                rightAmount = leftCurrency.convert(leftAmount, to: rightCurrency)
                            }
                        }
                }
                
                Image(systemName: "equal")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        
                        Text(rightCurrency.name)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        
                        Image(rightCurrency.image)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(height: 33)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        showSelectCurrency = true
                    }.sheet(isPresented: $showSelectCurrency){
                        SelectCurrency(showSelectCurrency: $showSelectCurrency, topCurrency: $leftCurrency, bottomCurrency: $rightCurrency)
                    }
                    
                    TextField("Amount", text: $rightAmount)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .focused($rightTyping)
                        .onChange(of: rightAmount) { newValue in
                            
                                leftAmount = rightCurrency.convert(rightAmount, to: leftCurrency)
                            
                        }
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .background(.black.opacity(0.5))
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                
                Button {
                    showInfoScreen = true
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }

            }
            .padding()
            .sheet(isPresented: $showInfoScreen) {
                InfoView(showInfoScreen: $showInfoScreen)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

and this is my func

```
func convert(_ amountString: String, to currency: Currency) -> String {
    
    guard let doubleAmount = Double(amountString) else {
        return "" // eğer kullanıcı textfield'a numara yerine harf yazarsa boş string return yapıyor yani textfield boş kalıyor
    }
    
    let convertedAmount = (doubleAmount / self.rawValue) * currency.rawValue
    
    return String(format: "%.2f", convertedAmount)
```

when I don't put the if statement everything works fine about converting, but when I put the if statement on the onChange it does nothing, no converts and nothing. I think I have to use the newValue on somewhere but I'm not sure so if you guys can help me with this problem.

This is my first question so I'm sorry if I couldn't explainn the best way.

I want to use that if statement about if right textfield is focused it'll type there and leave the other textfield, but when I put the if statement there, nothing works.

Comment: In your onChange you should just replace `rightAmount` with `newValue`, if that doesn't work then I believe there's an issue with your convert function. I can easily get it to work that way.

Comment: I've tried what you said and still nothing so I put the whole code and also the func if you can check it please @Joakim

Answer (score 1):

You are using the version of `.onChange` with one parameter that has been replaced in iOS 17.0, so it is now deprecated. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)) has a useful note:

> Be aware that the replacements have slightly different behvavior. This modifier’s closure captures values that represent the state before the change. The new modifiers capture values that correspond to the new state.

So inside your closures, the values are from before the change, with the important exception of `newValue`. For example, in this case:

```swift
.onChange(of: leftAmount) { newValue in
    if leftTyping {
        rightAmount = leftCurrency.convert(leftAmount, to: rightCurrency)
    }
}
```

the values for `leftTyping`, `leftCurrency`, `leftAmount` and `rightCurrency` are all from *before* the change.

#### Ways to try and fix

**1. Use the new version of `.onChange`**

You might find that it works if you use the new version of `.onchange` that takes two parameters:

```swift
.onChange(of: leftAmount) { _, newValue in
```

**2. Use `newValue` in the closure**

If the new version of `.onchange` is not an option (because you need to support older iOS versions) then try replacing `leftAmount` with `newValue` inside the closure:

```swift
.onChange(of: leftAmount) { newValue in
    if leftTyping {
        rightAmount = leftCurrency.convert(newValue, to: rightCurrency)
    }
}
```

The other case needs updating similarly - try replacing `rightValue` with `newValue` inside the closure (and add an `if` condition too).

**3. Use `newValue` to supply more information**

If making the simple change to the closure doesn't fix it then you will need to consider using a different value for the `.onChange`, so that `newValue` gives you more information. For example, you could use an empty string to indicate that the field did not have focus. Something like:

```swift
let leftAmountEntered = leftTyping ? leftAmount : ""
TextField("Amount", text: $leftAmount)
    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    .focused($leftTyping)
    .onChange(of: leftAmountEntered) { newValue in
        if !newValue.isEmpty {
            rightAmount = leftCurrency.convert(newValue, to: rightCurrency)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think I have a problem with the funcion because it still doesnt work. I really dont understand

Comment: @AlTheBeast Did you try all 3 suggestions? And did you add the missing `if` condition to the other `.onChange`? As a next step, you could try inspecting the values that are being used in the closures and in the conversion function. A few `print` statements might help as a start.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
TextField("Amount", text: $rightAmount)
    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
    .focused($rightTyping)
    .onChange(of: rightTyping) { newValue in
        if rightTyping {
            leftAmount = rightCurrency.convert(rightAmount, to: leftCurrency)
        }
```

Comment: Still same, not worked :(

Comment: now give it a try ?

Comment: I put the whole code, if you can check it also